# QT - exited with code -1073741511

Tags: qt

Well just recently i've tried to take a stab at using QT. But for the life of me i can't seem to get it to compile and keep getting the **exited with code -1073741511** error message. 
Right now i'm just simply trying to compile the "2dpainting example".

So just to confirm, im trying to compiling the 2dpainting example, it doesn't compile successfully.

In terms of the debugging output im getting, specifically it's seems these are they highlighted lines;

```
sException at 0x77671d32, code: 0xc0000139: DLL entry point not found, flags=0x1 (execution cannot be continued) in ntdll32!LdrpSnapThunk
sProcess exited (3221225785)
eProcess crashed
eCDB crashed
```

And the application output;

```
Starting C:\QtSDK\Examples\4.7\opengl\2dpainting-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_for_Desktop_-_MSVC2010__Qt_SDK__Debug\debug\2dpainting.exe...
The program has unexpectedly finished.
C:\QtSDK\Examples\4.7\opengl\2dpainting-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_for_Desktop_-_MSVC2010__Qt_SDK__Debug\debug\2dpainting.exe exited with code -1073741511
```

Not sure what to make of this, the application seems to start according to the compile output yet never pops up and automatically then crashes?

Help or an explanation of this error or what could be possible causing this would be great.

*For more info, im running Windows 7, 64 bit, Service Pack 1, i had already installed QT awhile back, say like a year ago but never got around to using it and uninstalled it, i believe when i had it back then i could indeed get these examples working.

Edit:
So after editing my PATH environment variable with the following;

```
C:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\msvc2010\bin;
```

& restarting Windows (Just to be sure), im still having no luck with Qt and am still achieving the same error message.

Edit:
So i just tried to compile the hello world example app in QT. Again it didn't work but this time i get these 3 warnings that are coming up, perhaps these related to the larger issue here?

Image below;
[image]

Zoom on errors :
[image: Zoom]

Comment: DLL entry point not found - I think this is the key. This article explain solution: http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/26604-Runtime-problem-in-Release-mode/page2