# Qt based code in Netbeans can be built, but fails in a Run

Tags: c++, qt, netbeans

I have successfully installed Netbeans7.4, Qt5.1.1 with Mingw, Msys. I'm working in Windows 7

Instead of writing any code I decided to follow the instructions given in the Qt installation web-page and went with the HelloQtWorld sample.

I can build the project, but when I Run the project I get the following error:

> RUN FAILED (exit value -1,073,741,511, total time: 60ms)

I have no clue how to interpret this message.

Comment: Tried to run it in a debugger? First guess would be that the Qt DLLs are not found at runtime (not in the PATH).

Comment: Yes. This is the error I get "During startup program exited with code 0xc0000139." There is nothing about Qt DLL

Answer (score 0):

All

There was a response given by Boris Ivanov at this page [QT - exited with code -1073741511](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293337/qt-exited-with-code-1073741511). Focus being on where in the PATH the order of the Qt, MingW, and Msys were situated.

Thanks you Boris.

For me they were at the end of the PATH. I put them at the beginning and lo and behold! (after restarting) the debug, build, and run all worked.

I do not fully understand why, but it works so try this solution if you have run into this situation